# Failure to upload all files - php

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to upload multiple files using AJAX. Works fine when there is only one file to upload in a form, but for some reason doesn't work when trying to upload two or more (only one gets updated, and usually the first one in the code).

here's the code for the form below:

```html
<form id="editPartnersForm" method="post" action="adminFunctions.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label for="partners_cover">partners_cover: </label>
  <label for="partners_pdf">partners_pdf: </label>
 
  <input id="partners_cover" type="text">

  <label for="jpgFile">Upload</label>
  <input class="ThisIsHiddenForAesthetics" type="file" name="jpgFile" id="jpgFile">

  <input class="uploadFileInput" id="partners_pdf" type="text">

  <label for="PDFFile">Upload</label>
  <input class="ThisIsHiddenForAesthetics" type="file" name="PDFFile" id="PDFFile">
 
 <input type="submit" value="Save" name="jpgUpload">
</form>
```

this is AJAX:

```js
$('#editPartnersForm').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var ID = $('.editPartnersModal').attr('rel');
  var partners_cover = $('#partners_cover').val();
  var partners_pdf = $('#partners_pdf').val();

  var formData = new FormData(this);
  formData.append('ElementID', ID);
  formData.append('partners_cover', partners_cover);
  formData.append('partners_pdf', partners_pdf);
  $.ajax({
    url: './adminFunctions.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function (response) {
      if (response == 1) {
        window.location.reload();
      }
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });
})
```

and the .php file:

```js
//          part 1 - pdf file            //
if(isset($_FILES["PDFFile"])) {

    $c = $_FILES["PDFFile"]["tmp_name"];
    if ($c === "") {
        die();
    }
    pdfFileF();
}
function pdfFileF() {
    $target_dir = "../path/folder/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["PDFFile"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["PDFFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
    }
}
//          part 2 - jpg file            //
if(isset($_FILES["jpgFile"])) {

    $c = $_FILES["jpgFile"]["tmp_name"];
    if ($c === "") {
        die();
    }
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["jpgFile"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        jpgFileF();
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
    }
}
function jpgFileF() {
    $target_dir = "../path/folder/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["jpgFile"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["jpgFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
    }
}
```

As for the .php file. the way code is now, only part one will be updated, while part two would remain unchanged. basically, whatever part is "on top", will only be updated. In similar modal where I have 3 file uploads, 1st and 3rd are updated only.

I know I am doing something wrong but honestly I've been about this bug for a long time, and I can't think of anything else to try and debug this.

any help is greatly appreciated! 
PS: I am fully aware that I didn't sanitize anything here, know I should so please skip that part. Thanks!

Comment: *"Failure to upload all files - php"* Did you get anny errors or checked for it also check the php errorlog file on server or the javascript console?

Comment: @RaymondNijland no errors in php errorlog file (except like file not found, when trying to open the page). no errors in JS either...

Answer (score 0):

Can you write your php script result?

In my local this script works like charm.
I suggest you to use xdebug.

Comment: I don't have a result. This is just a query to DB. this PHP script is part of admin page, when I add something through the form like these files or names, dates, etc. it updates my table in admin and DB correctly. it does everything except uploading the file to server. I see the result on index.php for example when I refresh (the pdf file or jpg is not uploaded).

Comment: maybe there permission problem? (dont have permission to write)

Comment: well if I switch places part one and part two (php file above), the first one on top will work. They have different folders... So I don't think it's about the permissions.